# Cognos Analytics Min(Date) and Max(Date) reporting same date and time for report why?

Tags: date, max, min, cognos

I've created a report form in COGNOS and have two singletons to display the data for minimum([Txn Date]) and maximum ([Txn Date]) but the both are returning the min date.

My aim is to pull the Start Time of the first transaction date and time and the End Time of the last transaction date and time.

How do I fix this please?

[image: Snippet of report in PDF view]

Comment: the min and max values of a single value will always match.  If you have more than one value, please share the input data.

Comment: If your data is sensitive (indicated in the image by redaction), reproduce the problem using the GO Sales (query) package and post the report spec.

Comment: You probably need to give the scope. Try this: 
minimum([Txn Date] for report)